# Pushing Images to Git Repo from Xcode

Tags: xcode, github, assets

So this problem already helped me solve another one of our issues, but I still haven't figured this one out. (This is relevant. Hold on.)

I am developing a game with one other person. Neither of us have ever used git repositories, Github (for more than reference) or any sort of version control before, and we've had some trouble getting set up.

We have our project set up in Xcode with remotes to a GitHub repo, and everything is working fine with the code. The problem is that we can't get our images (buttons, backgrounds, animations etc.) to commit to our local repo without resorting to one of two, very roundabout, methods.

1. Right click on our `Assets` group in Xcode and select `Add Files to Project`. I have to do this every time we add images anyway. Then, to get Xcode to realize that these are files that need to be added to the repo (at least to get the `A` indicator next to the files in the organizer) we have to go in and add a blank Objective-C class, then right click the `images > Source Control > Add`. Then delete the blank class.
2. Use the GitHub app to commit the project and push it from there. This isn't working because Github's `.gitignore` doesn't include the xcode preference files. This makes the project unable to commit from Xcode on any other machine, and even from the machine the commit was made from after a reboot. (This is the problem we figured out trying to commit images.)

So my question is: How do we share assets for the game? I figure that Xcode will do the same for sounds, we just haven't gotten there yet. Is there an easier way to get Xcode to recognize them? Or do we just need to add those user profile files to the `.gitignore` on GitHub? (And how do we do this?)

Answer (score 3):

Every one using Git just has to watch these two videos:

**Git For Ages 4 And Up**
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffBJ4sVUb4

**Advanced Git**
http://vimeo.com/49444883

1) I've found the best way to add images to my Xcode project is to just create the directory structure I want in the Finder then just drag and drop them from my finder in to the proper group in Xcode Project Navigator. Multi select all the new files, right click (control-click on a laptop) and select `Source Control` -> `Add`

And Bobs your uncle!

2) I do not use the GitHub app, I use SourceTree and the GitHub website. I've 20 years experience with command line source control systems but Xcode and SourceTree are so good the command line is no longer a part of my daily workflow.

I create a new Xcode project and check `Create local git repository for this project` then I go to the GitHub create a new repository with the same name as my project's top level directory. Copy the GitHub url. Drag the new project directory into SourceTree's Bookmarks window. Double Click on the new project view in SourceTree. Right mouse click on REMOTES and paste the GitHub url and enter origin/master for the name. Click the big push toolbar button.

[image: SourceTree's Bookmarks Window]

[image: Add a New Remote]

3) You need to add your user scheme and workspace file to .gitignore to push and pull from a remote you have to have a clean working repo. This is super simple with SourceTree just commit in Xcode and then open the project in SourceTree right click on the WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings and *.xccheme file and select `Ignore...` and it creates the .gitignore file for you. Now commit the .gitignore file and Push to the remote.

[image]

FYI: Check out SourceTree (http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) is's free in the Mac App Store. It's a very good GUI for Git. Atlassian makers of Jira acquired it and the original developer and released free to compliment the rest of there tools.